# How to open Windows Explorer maximized in Vista

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-vista

Every time I open Windows Explorer it is not maximized so I have to double click on the window header.

Is there some way to have it open maximized by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Tip #1 - Maximize Window Explorer window from shortcut**

[image]

**Tip #2 Registry Setting**

A little snooping in the registry turns up the MaximizeApps key.  I don’t know if this works on all apps or just Windows Explorer but I solved my problem.

Find this Key

```
* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\
* CurrentVersion\Explorer
```

Add a new DWORD value named “MaximizeApps”

```
* Set the value to 1
```

**Tip #3 use key short cut**

Open explorer, maximize and close it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>  pressed...

Comment: Tip #3 works perfectly thanks.  I guess i would have to do this initially each time i reboot my machine.  I'll check the registry tip as well after backing it up of course, as i assume it would then open maximized all the time.

Comment: A bonus tip for #1, if you like you can change the icon to `explorer.exe,0` to make the shortcut more realistic.

Answer (score 3):

Eusing's **[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)** will do that (and a lot more useful things) for you.

> **Automatically maximize** or minimize or normal **all new windows you
>   specify**.
>
> Automatically minimize all new windows
>   you specify to system tray.
>
> Automatically keep all new windows you
>   specify always on top.
>
> Adds several menu items to standard
>   window system menu.
>
> Minimize the current window to system
>   tray.
>
> Apply transparency effect from 0%
>   (fully transparent) to 100% (solid)
>   rate to any program in Windows
>   2000/XP/2003/Vista.
>
> Show window property of application,
>   such as window handle, class name,
>   process id etc.
>
> Auto Refresh Internet explorer at
>   custom intervals.

*AWM is freeware.*

Comment: Thanks for super speedy reply, will look into this.  I've noticed Xplorer2 Lite opens maximized by default so i guess that's another option.

Answer (score 0):

A VBscript that will do the tip #3 of @joe automatically (Windows 8+)

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "explorer.exe"
Wscript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.AppActivate "File explorer"
WshShell.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "+%{F4}"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Set `WshShell.AppActivate` to "This PC" if it is set be opened there.